Question about Gauss' Lemma proof in do Carmo
I have been reading through a proof of Gauss' Lemma in do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry".


But I have been having trouble understanding the following section:

Specifically, the statement that "$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is the tangent vector of a geodesic". I am confused how this follows from the equality
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = (d exp)_v(v)
$$
If anyone knows how to show this step in detail, it would be deeply appreciated :)

For any $p\in M$ and $v\in T_pM$, the curve $t\mapsto \exp_p(tv)$ is a geodesic (it starts at point $p$ with initial velocity $v$). Hence, $t\mapsto f(t,s)$ is a geodesic so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$ is the tangent vector to a geodesic.
